# Pull down initial app state to the store

Tags: react-redux, admin-on-rest

I'm working with admin on rest, and need to pull down all of the resources on load. This is because I cross link resources. Unfortunately, trying to use these links without having visited the resource yet yields empty and broken components.

I haven't found anyone with this problem in the issues on github, or anything with good relationship to my issue here.

Can someone lend an assist with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A neat but mildly hacky way to achieve this would be to connect a small single pixel size component to state, and then shoot a GET_LIST action for that resource when the component loads.

Will load all your data on loading

Comment: They allow an `initialState` prop to be passed to the `<Admin>` component and link to the redux `createStore` method for how to do it, but I'm having trouble squaring away how to structure that state tree to match with AoR's idea of what the state tree should look like.

Comment: That must be a new feature that I am not aware of. You can just connect any component to redux and log the entire state and examine the structure.